# Django PayPal - When process does not complete

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

I have setup django-paypal and its working fine. The only problem I have is that the post to my server about the transaction is only sent to me when the user either clicks on the "return to merchant website" or it redirects after 5 seconds.
MY question is what happens if the user never clicked on the button? Then I will never know about the transaction?

Or am I missing something? I tried both PDT and IPN. I was under the impression it would be send as soon as the transaction was successfull?

Comment: This seems so simple to me? How come there is no clear way to do this? Im sure its the way it should be from Paypal

Comment: Well I think Webhooks should do the job?